# My keil5 doesn't make RTE_Device.h(Startup) in new projects

Tags: stm32, keil

When I create a new project, I choose my micro controller(stm32f407VG) and check "CMSIS" and "`Startup`" in Manage Runtime Time Environment, but it doesn't build "`RTE_Device.h(Startup)`" under Device in project menu!

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

**Project** - **New uVision Project** - Choose your micro-controller.

Keil uVision 5 should specifically ask you:

> Copy 'Startup.s' to Project Folder and Add File to Project ?

If for some reason or other, this is not the case in your project:

1. Right Click on `Source Group 1`
2. Click on Add New Item to Group 'Source Group 1'
3. Click on Asm FIle (.s)

This will act as your startup.s file.

You may want to read further, [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_ca_config_start_code.htm).